# How can I use delta cache function in local spark cluster mode?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

I'd like to test [delta-cache](https://docs.databricks.com/optimizations/disk-cache.html#configure-cache) in local cluster mode (jupyter)

### 1. What I want to do:

Whole delta-formatted files aren't re-downloaded every time, only new data will be re-downloaded

### 2. What I've tried

```py
...
# cell1
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.io.cache.enabled", "true")

# cell2
spark.sql("""
CREATE TABLE my_table2
USING DELTA
LOCATION 'MY_S3_DELTA_FORMATTED_PATH';
""")

# cell3
import time
s = time.time()
spark.sql("select * from my_table2").show()
print(time.time() - s)
```

But `cell3` shows the same time taken every time I run the cell, which means that the table is not cached.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.databricks.com/optimizations/disk-cache.html

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/sql-ref-syntax-aux-cache-cache-table.html

Disk cache is different to Spark caching using SQL.

Read the links. Then I think the difference will be apparent. You have missed something.

You need `CACHE ... TABLE...`.

Comment: Isn't `CACHE ... TABLE...` a spark a cache, not a delta cache?

Comment: Suggest you read and work out the differences.

Comment: I've already read once, and seen `When the disk cache is enabled,  Data that has to be fetched from a remote source is automatically added to the cache.` , `CACHE SELECT` is just for forcing to cache... isn't it?

Comment: 2 totally different concepts, I'm leaving it at this. Success.